# svelte list won't update when I add to an array

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm just starting out with svelte... so, this is probably a noob question.

I have a list, and I can remove items from the array and the list (#each) updates no problems.

...but if I add an item to the array the list doesn't redraw until I remove another item...

https://svelte.dev/repl/ef316351462a434691388351aef1676a?version=3.44.0

Comment: Don’t use push for update the array, use spread operator, like this tickets = [...tickets, newItem];

Comment: ah, as in create a new array with the extra entry, rather than push an entry onto the old array? does svelte watch for the array being replaced or something?

Comment: thankyou, I used the spread operator, and it now works as expected.
https://svelte.dev/repl/16a22798ab1a49468d08dedf1bffee1d?version=3.44.0

Comment: For checking reactivity svelte check assign operator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For reactivity Svelte check assign operator. So use spread operator or reassign the variables.

```js
//Short Syntax 
tickets = [...tickets, newTicket]

// Or
tickets.push(newTicket);

tickets = tickets;
```